# Tasks with LinkedList nodes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, closures

I have multiple tasks and each starts at a given `LinkedListNode`. Something like this:

```
first = linkedList.First;
int counter = 0;
while (iterator != null) {
    counter++;
    if (counter == threshold) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => run(first, iterator));
        counter = 0;
        first = iterator.Next;
    }
    iterator = iterator.Next;
}
```

The idea is that I want to run through a `LinkedList` and not convert it to an array because of memory requirements. So, I figured I'd just pass in the start and the end and iterate over that.

When my tasks actually start, it seems like the parameters are where ever they left off in the loop. Is there some way I can form a closure over the variables so that the task starts with the correct nodes from the `LinkedList`?

Or, maybe a better way of accomplishing this goal with a `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to variable closure, you should declare the variable that is captured in your lambda expression *within* the body of your loop. Otherwise, the task's reads of the `first` variable would suffer a race condition with the main thread's subsequent updates to it.

```
first = linkedList.First;
while (iterator != null) 
{
    // ...
    var current = first;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => run(current));
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your linked list instead. This looks like it will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: This, and with an appropriate `Partitioner` if the `threshold` is an important factor.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass state to your Task [through the appropriate `StartNew` method which takes an `object` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd321456.aspx). A closure is automatically performed over the data passed in this way to the Task.